# Scala: why using `_` as a lambda expression body to be used as a function argument does not work?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

For example,

```
scala> val a = Set(Array(1, 2),Array(8, 9))
a: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Array[Int]] = Set(Array(1, 2), Array(8, 9))

scala> a.flatMap(_)
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => a.flatMap(x$1))
              a.flatMap(_)
                        ^

scala> a.flatMap(x=>x)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 8, 9)
```

Is there a shortcut for `x=>x` type of lambda function?

Comment: what is the need for `a.flatMap(_)` ? you can use `a.flatten`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `identity`,

```
val a = Set(Array(1, 2) ,Array(8, 9))

a.flatten

a.map(identity).flatten
```

If you go into identity its like

```
@inline def identity[A](x: A): A = x
```

So it works same as `x => x`, whatever comes just return as it is.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know there's an `identity` function. I do have a scenario where I need to `map` a `Seq` of key-value tuples to a `Map` instance which can use `identity` or `x=>x`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use simple flatten.

```
scala> val a = Set(Array(1, 2),Array(8, 9))
//a: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Array[Int]] = Set(Array(1, 2), Array(8, 9))

scala> a.flatten
//res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 8, 9)

scala> a.map(x => x).flatten
//res9: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 8, 9)
```

Here, `a.map(f)` where f is `A => B` conversion function required. Other wise type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Since your title asks why it doesn't work, and not just how to make it work: the error message tells you.

When `_` is used directly as an argument of a method, its scope expands so that `a.flatMap(_)` is `x => a.flatMap(x)`. This is simply useful much more often: would you want `println(_)` to always print `<function1>`?